# How to print only first few lines of output through python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, large-data

Is there a special method/function to print only first few lines of output in python 2.7. We know that in terminal we could do that through "$head -3 " for seeing first 3 lines. do I have to just write a python for loop.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that loop would be 2 lines long, which is exactly one more line longer than `head -3`.

Comment: Yes ... `for i in xrange(3): print next(...)`

Comment: If you want to go with a few characters, you can go for text[:30] for the first 30 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for i in xrange(3):
        print f.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys 

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n 
        self.count = 0 
        self.terminal = sys.stdout


    def write(self, message):
        self.count+=1
        if self.count<self.n:
            self.terminal.write(message)


sys.stdout = Logger(10)
```

Now when you using print only first 10 lines will be printed, the other one will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I am working with large xml's which produce more output than console let to show.
I am using:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

print etree.tostring(large_xml_root)[0:300]
```

to see only the beginning of this xml.

This isn't precisely what you were asking for, but I get to this post looking for something like above solution.